# Cafe Food Menu upload

Tags: visual-editor, post-formats

A funky cafe changes their menu every month, and they're not comfortable with using the default Wordpress editor to make a Wordpress page look the same as their Word doc.  [Example word doc here](http://www.louisbaxters.com.au/Lunch_Menu.docx).

Can you think of a way to get this menu to display nicely as HTML inside [their website](http://www.louisbaxters.com.au)?

Comment: To recreate the word document in the visual editor is very easy. All I can see here is use of bold/italic/headings and paragraphs. Just edit the theme CSS to re-produce this.

Answer (score 1):

Rock the [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)? You could do this manually or by using a plugin such as [magic fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields-2/) or [PODS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/).

I've never used PODS but I've been eying it for a while and think this may be your best route. You could do something like creating a category called "breakfast" and one called "lunch" then two text fields:

1) Item Name
2) Item Price

then

```
$pods = new Pod('breakfast');
$pods->findRecords('name ASC', 99);

while ($pods->fetchRecord()) {
    echo $pods->get_field('item');
    echo $pods->get_field('price');
}
```

They would then just have to add and remove food items based on month.

Comment: Yes, +1 for PODS :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a plugin called Simple Retail Menus ( http://whatwouldjessedo.com/simple-retail-menus/ )  I am using on a simple site that I am developing for a small grocery and deli.  I have customized it with CSS.  Here is an example of what I have done with it http://cutterswc.com/cottondale/category/menu/